# Cannot find path using FileUpload ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, file-upload

```
FileUpload objControl = (FileUpload)Page.Form.FindControl("cphMain").FindControl(sColumnName);
//check if file upload has a file name before saving
if (objControl.HasFile)
{
   sSingleValue = Path.GetFileName(objControl.PostedFile.FileName);
                            uploadFiles.Add(sColumnName, objControl);
   fStream = File.OpenRead(Path.GetFullPath(objControl.PostedFile.FileName));
   contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
   fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
   fStream.Close();
 }
 else
 {
   blInclude = false;
 }
```

Im using the code above to take a pdf file from the fileupload and convert it to bytes which I will then use to save the file to a SQL DB. When the site is deployed to a server and I am accessing it on my machine its giving me an error (but its running fine on a dev machine where I am running locally)

If I change the code to upload the file into the website directory the pdf is being written to the database containing all zeros.

Exception information: 
Exception type: DirectoryNotFoundException 
Exception message: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\gavin\documents\test.pdf'

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you checked MSDN for sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?  your expectation to find client's file on server is somewhat strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to do a `File.OpenRead` on a file path that is A.) most likely only the filename because the file upload doesn't contain the path and B.) even if the `FileName` *did* have the file path it would be local to your machine, but this code is running on the server and therefore can't access that path anyway. It works when you run it locally because the server and the machine you're uploading from are the same.

You don't need to do any of this anyway. The `PostedFile` property of the upload control has an `InputStream` that contains the bytes of the file. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (objControl.HasFile)
{
   sSingleValue = Path.GetFileName(objControl.PostedFile.FileName);
   uploadFiles.Add(sColumnName, objControl);   
   contents = new byte[objControl.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];
   objControl.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(contents, 0, 
       (int)objControl.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave. I just tried it on the dev machine and its running fine. Need to wait until tomorrow to deploy to test env again so I can test but will let you know then. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Np. Let me know if you have questions!

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you have full permission to do those activities on a physical path that corresponds to the virtual directory. Give permission for the following group -"IIS_IUSRS".That user will need Create / Write / Modify permissions to the corresponding physical path.If the users doesn't have enough permission,He can't do any operations like Create/Read/Write.